# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser, find text inside tags that have no class nor id

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I have a http://www.statistics.com/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=703

Specifically in these part:

```
<b>Additive Error:</b>
<p> Additive error is the error that is added to the true value and does not 
depend on the true value itself. In other words, the result of the measurement is 
considered as a sum of the true value and the additive error:   </p>
```

I tried my best to get the text between the tag `<p>` and `</p>`, with this:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.statistics.com/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=703';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($curl_scraped_page);

foreach ( $html->find('b') as $e ) {
echo $e->innertext . '<br>';
}
```

It gives me:

```
Additive Error:
Browse Other Glossary Entries
```

I tried to change the foreach to: `foreach ( $html->find('b p') as $e ) {`

then `foreach ( $html->find('/b p') as $e ) {`

Then it just keeps giving me nothing but blank page.
What did I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use PHP's built-in DOM extension and xpath?

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  // <- you might needs this if that page has errors
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($curl_scraped_page);
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
print $xpath->evaluate('string(//p[preceding::b]/text())');
//                             ^
//  this will get you text content from <p> tags preceded by <b> tags
```

If there are multiple `<p>` tags preceeded by `<b>`'s, and you want to get just the first one, adjust the xpath query to:

```
string((//p[preceding::b]/text())[1])
```

To get them all as a `DOMNodeList`, ommit the `string()` function: `//p[preceding::b]/text()` and then you can iterate over the list and access the `textContent` property of each node...

Comment: Oh My God, you save my life! Thank you so much.. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, I have another problem. I want to do some parsing from other pages, but I read that we can't create new object before deleting the previous one. My question is: how do I delete that $dom before I create some `simple_html_dom` object? Thank you,,

Comment: By assigning a new object to the variable, eg `$dom = new DomDocument()` ... But why use "simple_html_dom" and not DomDocument directly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all content which is inside b or p tags, you can simply do `foreach ($html->find('b,p') as $e) { ... }`.

Comment: No, I just want the text inside the p tag above, that one only.. What do I do?

Comment: If you only want exactly that one, I suspect you might be kind of screwed. I'd help you but I have no idea how.

Comment: Yea, u're right. I'm screwed, :( I've been in this thing for quite long, and yet I keep failing with the code. D'u think it's possible to do this?

Comment: It might be, but I don't know how. You could look for p tags preceded by b tags, as per One Trick Pony's (excellent) solution, but you'll always run the risk of returning multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Yea, I just took a look at it. Thank God, thanks to you too. :) Fortunately each link with different term_id only has one b tag followed by p tag. It will be all right, won't it?

Comment: If you're lucky, yes. I hope you get the results you're looking for. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.statistics.com/index.php?page=glossary&term_id=703');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$mytext = '';
foreach($xpath->query('//font') as $font){
    $mytext =  $xpath->query('.//p', $font)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    break;
}

echo $mytext;
?>
```

Comment: I just want the text inside that p tag above, that one only.. What do I do?